# MapInfo - writing text using polylines

Tags: mapinfo

I am looking for a way to create text on a MapInfo layer using Polylines.  So on a MapInfo layer, I need to create a line dataset, but I am after forming words - labelling items is not going to work for me.  Are there any tools that can help do this?  I have tried doing it freehand using a polyline, and a polyline with autonode mode selected, but frankly it looks rubbish

Comment: If I read your question right, you want to create text using polylines?

Out of curiosity, can I ask why you're trying to do that? What is that you are attempting to achieve? There might be an alternative solution to get to your end goal.

Comment: basically I want to create a layer of watermarks as a vector layer - labelling grids etc is not working satisafactorily in my use case.

Comment: Could you use a layer of text objects instead?

Comment: text gets converted to points unfortunately